# После настройки pg_hba.conf отваливается прослушивание порта

Tags: postgresql

1)

```
drm@test:~$ sudo netstat -antup | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29926/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      29926/postgres
```

но после добавления своего IP адреса в pg_hba и рестарта сервера

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             192.168.36.21           md5
```

получаю пусто

```
drm@test:~$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql
drm@test:~$ sudo netstat -antup | grep 5432
drm@test:~$
```

т.е. сервер ничего не слушает и подключиться с удаленного компа нет возможности

Comment: `192.168.36.21` - тут не указана маска сети. попробуйте добавить.

Comment: Спасибо большое, так и есть, заработало!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте вопрос своему `systemctl` куда и зачем он спрятал сообщение о том, что база не запустилась.

А база именно не запустилась, т.к. в hba у вас ошибка, IP адрес должен быть указан с маской сети.

Впрочем, рестарт для изменения hba не нужен вовсе, достаточно `reload`. Тогда база перечитает конфиги, в случае синтаксических ошибок напишет об этом в лог, но продолжит работать на старой версии настроек. Если ошибок нет - начнёт использовать новый конфиг.